# PJSIP iOS video call

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, pjsip

I want to implement video call using pjsip but unable to integrate the same. Audio call is working fine at my end. Could you please guide me how to implement video call in iOS version? Any clue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?